# How do I send a Minecraft Resource Pack to someone

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I play on Windows Bedrock Edition and I have made a resource pack I want to send to a friend but I don't know how to, I've searched it up on google but i can't find anything on it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the resource pack is in a folder:
Right-click the folder and compress it into a `.zip` archive. Place the folder in a Google Drive, and have them download it and put it in their `Minecraft/games/resource_packs` folder.

Assuming it's a `.mcpack` or `.zip`:
You can just send it to them and have them manually extract it at the source. If it's a `.mcpack`, they can simply open it in Minecraft to self-extract.